# General rule for what can be inside of a chain in Spring Integration

Tags: jpa, spring-integration

I need to use a JPA retrieving outbound gateway and I would like to chain it with a header enricher. Trying to do this I went over the documentation to understand if there is a general rule to know if an endpoint could be inside of a chain or not. I couldn't find the rule of thumb on what can be or not.

My particular case I'm trying to do this:

```
<int:chain input-channel="audTrailRetrievalChannel" output-channel="updateResponseForTestSent">
    <int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway id="getAudTrail" jpa-query="select e.details from AudTrail e where e.audTrailRecId = :id" entity-manager-factory="auditEntityManager">
        <int-jpa:parameter name="id" expression="payload?.body?.response?.responseInformation?.communicationVariables?.variable.?[variableName=='audTrailRecId'][0]?.variableValue"/>
    </int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="registerMethod" value="registerAuditTrail" overwrite="true"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything within a chain but an outbound channel adapter or router (anything that does not have an output channel - implement `MessageProducer`) must be the last element.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain